# How to use SkipDefaultCheckout in a scripted pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to use Options `{ SkipDefaultCheckout(True) }` in scripted pipeline.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [the answer from here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/650/set-a-jenkins-job-to-not-to-clone-the-repo-in-scm/1074)

```
node {
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        //...
}
```