# Despite skipDefaultCheckout true Jenkins still clones repository

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops

Despite using skipDefaultCheckout true it still CLONES the git repo. 
My goal is just to look for changes and then execute certain scripts.
 I've run out of ideas. I tried this [How to use SkipDefaultCheckout in a scripted pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128015/how-to-use-skipdefaultcheckout-in-a-scripted-pipeline), but I quess it doesn't work?

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout true
  }
   environment {
       branch = 'test'
   }
  stages {
    stage('commit_stage') {
      steps {
        script {
          properties([pipelineTriggers([pollSCM('*/5 * * * *')])])
          git branch: "${branch}", credentialsId: 'test', url: 'https://gitlab.test.net/core/test.git'
          sh '''
          branch=${branch}
          ssh bamboo@app-test.synchr.net "cd /opt/${branch}-8*/ && ./startup.sh status"
             '''
                }
          //define scm connection for polling

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The option `skipDefaultCheckout` is to prevent checking out a repository automatically in the build agent when you haven’t explicitly defined a checkout step in one of your stages. But it will still checkout the repository to fetch the Jenkinsfile if you haven’t selected **Lightweight checkout** under **Pipeline script from SCM**.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you've just got the syntax wrong for the option. You've got:

```
  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout true
  }
```

It should be

```
  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout()
  }
```

[Pipeline Syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct: https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses
Groovy allows this and Jenkinsfile is written in groovy.

I just stumble around this post and it didn't help me. My guess is that the checkout needs to be outside the script.