# How to have the pipeline checked out on Jenkins-agent (scripted pipeline)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I specify a new job in Jenkins and configure to checkout the "Pipeline script from SCM", this repo will be checked out on the jenkins-agent (if it is a declarative pipeline).
I do have a Makefile right next to my pipeline-description that's being used from within that pipeline.

Now I migrated that pipeline to a scripted pipeline (instead of a declarative one).
Unfortunately jenkins now only checks out the repository on the Jenkins-master, so that the agent doesn't have the Makefile available any longer.

I tried to play around with the `skipDefaultCheckout()` function that is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128015/how-to-use-skipdefaultcheckout-in-a-scripted-pipeline), but this doesn't help.

I want the repo with my scripted pipeline (and the makefile) to be available on the agent as well. Is there such a possibility?

Comment: You would probably need to code the retrieval with the `SCM` class.

Comment: are you sure there is no other way? Following your suggestion I'd have to specify the repo/branch redundantly (once in the job and once in the pipeline). As soon as I branch/merge in my pipeline-repo I'll risk to point to two different locations. And it does work when it's a declarative pipeline :/

Comment: In the scripted pipeline within the node directive you can just call `checkout scm` to clone the repository configured for the pipeline script.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted :) Thank you. If you post this as an answer I will accept it as solution :)